# Initialising jQuery DataTables in Wordpress Breaking HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatables

I've been working with DataTables in Wordpress but ran into a weird issue which seems like a wordpress specific problem.

I can initialise the jQuery DataTable without a problem using:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    jQuery('#test_table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
} );
} );
</script>
```

But the jQuery functionality disappears rendering the table back to plain html when I use:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    jQuery('#test_table tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = jQuery('#test_table').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        jQuery( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

It doesn't make sense because both of the above work fine in jsfiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm that your Datatables code works fine, so it's probably some interaction with Wordpress. Can you provide more info on how you're including this code in WP?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Please see the answer below. I got it working I have no idea why the new code makes a difference. I simply moved var table = jQuery('#test_table').DataTable(); to line 2. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply that makes sense,

Im enqueueing my .js file as described here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

After an excruciating few hours I managed to get it working with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var table = jQuery('#test_table').DataTable();
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    jQuery('#test_table tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    });
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;
        jQuery( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
    });
    });
});
```

I moved

```
var table = jQuery('#test_table').DataTable();
```

to line 2.

If anyone else runs into this problem my setup is:

Wordpress 5.0.3
Plugins:
Formidable Forms 3.0.5
Formidable Forms Pro 3.0.5